# Extracting the right values from strings

Tags: c++

```
   int a = 10;
   int b = 5;
   char test[]= "bread";

   a = a + test[0];

   cout << a << endl;
```

Basically i want to use the value of the integer b. In this example the first char of the string is a 'b' so i want to use the value of b and not the ascii value.

I tried casting it like this but did not work.

```
 a = a + (int)test[0];
```

The cout should be 15;

Comment: c, c++ and c# are _completely different languages_. please just tag the one you're _actually_ using. i also recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I changed it to c++ thank you.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. You will need to write appropriate logic to choose the right variable to use, using an `if`, or maybe a `switch` statement.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Or [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to obtain values from names.

Comment: Seems like you wanna hash variable names and extract their values at runtime, which I seriously doubt it's what you mean. You probably mean hashing constant values under alphabet (charset) char keys. In the ASCII charset for example, 'b' equals to 98 which you can use as the hash-key of 'b', with hash-value = 5 in your hash-table (an array for example). Then array['b'] (or array[98]) will give you back 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable names don't exist at runtime. You could use a `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`) to associate names with values. Simple example:

```
std::map<char, int> variables;

variables['a'] = 10;
variables['b'] = 5;
std::string test = "bread"; // In C++ prefer std::string over char[]

variables['a'] = variables['a'] + variables[test[0]];

cout << variables['a'] << endl; // Prints 15
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature you want can only be properly supported in a very dynamic language, like python or tcl. C++ is a compile time language, it has no idea about what your variable b's name means, to the compiler it's just some random symbol. You might change b to abcde, and compiler won't care less.

Once you gave up on the variable name, there is still something that can do.

```
std::map<char, int> some_map;
some_map['b'] = 5;
char test[]= "bread";
int a = 10;
a += some_map[test[0]];
cout << "a = " << a << endl;
```